# Number of simple, connected (labelled) graphs

Tags: graph-theory, recursion

If $d_n$ denotes the number of connected simple graphs, then $$d_n = \displaystyle{\sum_k} {n\choose k} k d_k 2^{{n−k} \choose 2}$$

Can anyone explain how the recursion works without the use of generating functions? I am trying to justify using combinatorial arguments but that doesn't seem easy.

After thinking about this for sometime now I arrived at this :

Consider a graph having $n$ vertices. Consider a pool of $n-k$ vertices and another set of the remaining $k$ vertices. Now we can generate as many as $2^{n-k \choose 2}$ graphs (not necessarily connected) from those $n-k$ vertices. The remaining $k$ vertices can be chosen in $n \choose k$ ways and mutually connected in $d_k$ ways. A particular vertex (say $V$) from this set of $k$ vertices will connect all the vertices of the remaining $n-k$ vertices (the set of vertices chosen initially) and this $V$ can be chosen in $k$ ways.

This gives the formula I think but I cannot understand why this might be distinct/unique and/or not over-count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OEIS sequence A001187](https://oeis.org/A001187) is "Number of connected labeled graphs with n nodes". To prove
$$  n\, 2^{n \choose 2} = n\, d_n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {n\choose k} k\, d_k\, 2^{{n−k} \choose 2} \tag1 $$ 
consider the number of "pointed" labeled graphs. That is, labeled graphs
with a selected node.
The left side of equation $(1)$ is the number of pointed labeled graphs
with $n$ nodes. There are now two cases.
In the first case, the graph is connected and $\,n\,d_n\,$ is the number of pointed labeled connected graphs. In the second case, consider the connected component of the selected node which has $\,k < n\,$ nodes. The number of such is $\,k\,d_k\,$
and the nodes can be chosen in $\,{n\choose k}\,$ ways. The remaining $\,n-k\,$ nodes contribute $\,2^{{n−k} \choose 2}\,$ labeled graphs.

Your idea was very similar to mine, but you used an incorrect equation.

Comment: I see, that makes so much sense now! The introduction of this selection of nodes makes it so much solvable. That over-count on the LHS and the RHS due to this "pointed nodes" can be evaluated well without flaw.